# Parse JSON into a JCR Node

Tags: json, rest, jcr

Currently developing an app for observing changes in a JCR Repository and replicate this changes to another repository. I can't rely on a cluster JCR cause the two repositories won't be on the same network, and the connection is not reliable, so my implementation takes care of the communication problem using a REST API between the two servers, and give some fault tolerance guarantees. The problem is I need to serialize nodes, preferably in a JSON format, and parse that JSON into a Node on the other side.

I've tried Apache Sling, using some internal classes it can serialize perfectly the node into a JSON format, but I can't seem to find a way to deserialize into a Node Object on the other side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Sling POST Servlet can import JSON content, see "importing content structures" at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html

Another option is the new replication module that has recently been contributed, that might be just what you need. It's at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/contrib/extensions/replication/ , there might not be any docs yet but if you ask on the [Sling users mailing list](http://sling.apache.org/project-information.html#mailing-lists) I'm sure you'll get help on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wish I could use some class to do that. I was building the server side with play framework and akka to be as parallel and ligthweight as possible. Maybe if I take a pic inside those sling servlets codes I can, then, use some of their classes to get where I want. And I'll be sure to take a good look at the replication extension, maybe if possible contribute a little. Nice answer.